# My site is displaying some errors SQL related

Tags: mysql, warnings

I am not an developer and have limited knowledge. My site is displaying the following errors at the top...Its a wordpress site.

Can you guys help without being too technical. I have shielded server name for security purposes

> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/.....and line 118
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home./(servername)/public_html/wp-content/themes/clip/header.php on line 118
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/(servername) /public_html/wp-content/themes/clip/header.php on line 14

Comment: Mysql is saying I need a password and WordPress hasn't given it one.

Comment: So, can you explain how do I then resolve this? Is it by logging into the wp back-end and from there?

Comment: This is a legitimate problem but as it's not programming related it's not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have access to the sql database with your account. Maybe give away how you connect to the database to see what's going on? And there are a lot of ressources about this specific problem, I think you didn't look that much into it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Our developers have not been resourceful, hence we seeking some sorta diy help here. Like i said i dont understand the technicals but can log into my cpanel (linux) and wp-admin back-end. If you can guide as to how to connect to the database, would be helpful

Comment: I need to see the code to know how you connected to the database and help you out. If you don't know how you connected to your database, I can't really hep.

Comment: i hope this helps:

Comment: Hi guys - I have a bit of an update. Went through my wp-config file and mysql database and I have noticed that the database name on wp-config is not the same with the one on mysql database. Could it be that I have moved from one hosting to another, hence i am getting these errors?...It doesnt add up but i wanna make sure because i make changes on the wp-config.